# Python, keyword searching code in a large .log file

Tags: python, file, directory, readfile, writefile

im new to python and im building a keyword searching program that´s supposed to find every word that´s the same in a larg .log file (for now, word "Time stamp") and store the values in seperate .log file.

This is the code i have written and my problem is that i only get the first time "Time stamp" pops upp in the .log text new file, not the +100 other times that i want  to it...

HELP? :)

---

def search(filename, text): 
    important = []

```
with open(filename) as f:   #open search file
    f = f.readlines()   #read searrch file
for lines in f:
        if text in lines:   #if keyword is found take all lines
            important.append(lines) #store all found keywords
            print('done')
            break
    # file or 'sorted.txt'
with open('sorted.log', 'w') as file_handler:
      file_handler.write(f"{filename}\n Status: {important} \n")

search(r'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\search\OJW74.log', 'Time stamp:') # search path
```

---

***ex. (the .log file locks like this)

```
Complete Response: 1636 59 02 FF
Time stamp: 9792463
Time between request and response(P2 time): 42 ms

Complete Response: 1636 59 02 FF
Time stamp: 9392463
Time between request and response(P2 time): 42 ms

Complete Response: 1636 59 02 FF
Time stamp: 9794463
Time between request and response(P2 time): 42 ms
...................
....................***
```

Comment: The first time you find your text, you `break` out of the loop. Try removing the `break`

Answer (score 1):

The `break` line in your for loop will end the loop entirely, so it will only ever call `important.append(lines)` once - the `break` serves no purpose here.

Also I'm assuming your `print('done')` line should be two indentation levels to the left to signify that the loop has finished!

Comment: Thanks, revoving break and the indentation help! now i get every value :), but they are all witten after each other on the same line, is there some way to fix that also? so that one value is displayd on every line and not on the same